# Свернуть замыкание {...} в xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Добрый день, в каком-то видео видел, что можно скрыть содержимое внутри `{}` в xcode, как при работе с джсоном например, гуглил не нашел, может кто подскажет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в настройках xcode ставим галочку [image: xcode] на code folding ribbon, после чего рядом с нумерацией строк появится полоска, щелкнув по которой, Вы сможете свернуть содержимое нужного блока.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ставите курсор после первой фигурной скобки `{` и нажимаете `alt + cmd + стрелочка влево` (`⎇ + ⌘ + ←`)

Comment: спасибо огромное!!